# UPDATE con varias tablas

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos tengo este script:

`UPDATE asistencia
SET fecha = "30/12/2019"
FROM asistencia AS asis
INNER JOIN  vehiculouser as vehus ON asis.idvehuser = vehus.idvehuser AND vehus.placa = "def123"
WHERE fecha = "01/01/2020"`

pero resulta que cuando lo corro me dice que tengo un error en en la linea 3 y la verdad no se que pasa.

Lo que quiero hacer es un update pero tengo que validar antes en la tabla vehiculouser la placa a la que se le tiene que hacer la actualizacion y eso es lo que no he podido hacer.

agradeceria mucho su ayuda con este tema.

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero, prueba remover el  `AS asis`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que pena ponerlos en a pensar por mi.

Pero ya encontre la solucion al problema que tenia fue la siguiente:

```
UPDATE asistencia AS A, vehiculouser AS V
SET fecha = "31/12/2019"
WHERE A.idvehuser = V.idvehuser AND V.placa = "def123" AND fecha = "30/12/2019"
```

Agradezco a las personas que alcanzaron a leer esta pregunt y pensar en su posible solución.